# MySQL POP Last Row and Delete it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a queue system in MySQL, I wish to "POP" the last row and delete it at the same time. I have multiple scripts that would be selecting from the queue table, so it cannot retrieve the same row twice.

Is there a better command than `SELECT` then `DELETING` the `ROW ID`?

Comment: If you need to get the data from the last row before deleting it, then that's the best way. Use a transaction to ensure that no other process can insert another row in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer:** No :)

**Explanation:** You mentioned you need two actions to take place:

1. Obtain the last row
2. Delete the last row

That would require two queries to enter your database. the `SELECT` operator is the tool given to you to obtain any row you want. It of course does matter how you use the `SELECT` operator. If `WHERE name = 'sam'` is being executed on a column that is not indexed, then the speed of the query could suffer. The amount it would suffer depends on the size of your database of course and it might be negligable, however that is why the conditional at the end of your query usually is executed on an indexed field like the `PRIMARY KEY` for instance.

As for deleting the row, `DELETE` is the only tool you have, and I'm sure that even if there was another tool that it's efficiency wouldn't be better than using `DELETE`, since our dear friends that developed SQL would surely notice the enhanced efficiency and modify `DELETE` to be just as efficient.

Comment: What kind of index could I use if I were to just retrieve a random row in the table? (there would be gaps once I start deleting random rows in the table)

Comment: @Lanbo there wouldn't be gaps per say... rather you'll just have your IDs like 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 when deleting the row with ID=5. Also, if you want to retrieve a random row, your best option is just to use the mt_rand() function in php for a specific range. Also, if this answer was the one that helped you, please accept the answer (green check mark) so that future users know it helped you.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply.

If I have the ID's: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8
and I used mt_rand(1,8) I would get the value "5" 1/8th of a time, resulting me in selecting a NULL ID (5) from the rows.

Comment: You would get the value 1/8 th of the time in that situation yes. If the value would be NULL entirely depends on what is being extracted from the table in your database, however if NULL is what is inside, then that is correct.

Comment: Is there anyway to quickly randomize and pull a row from the table without hitting any of those NULL rows?

Comment: Yes, you can preform a select query similar to `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID != NULL`. From there, if your using PDO::MySQL (which I highly recommend you do), you can preform a row count like this `$rowcount = $stmt->rowCount()`. That way you'll know how many rows you have selected in your query, and from there you can use `$randValue = mt_rand(1,$rowcount)` to get a random value for your new range. Once you have that new random value, all you do is fetch the rows into an array using `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll()`, and then you can just use `$rows[$randValue]` to extract the row.

Comment: Thanks! Would this be scalable, to let's say a table with 1,000,000 rows and thousands of queries a minute, it seems like if it has to count the # of rows each time it would slow it down tremendously?

Comment: So in SQL you have the ability to index certain columns. For example, whenever you make a column a `PRIMARY KEY`, that column will become indexed. Indexing is basically some internal code sql will do to put everything in order. If you index a column with strings, there will be an index somewhere in the database with all the strings placed in alphabetical order so that it is easy to find. This is important to have on tables that are big (such as 1000000 rows) because it increases the speed drastically.

Comment: For this very reason, the value you have in your `WHERE ...` conditional should always be an index value, like your `PRIMARY KEY`. For example: `WHERE ID = 4`, given that ID is the primary key, or `WHERE MESSAGE = 'HELLO'` and given that MESSAGE was indexed. If you want to know how to index, a simple google search will bring you a lot of good results: "SQL how to index columns"